# UIPanGestureRecognizer not working if the UIImageView is Scaled too much in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a UIImageView, in which different gestures like  UIPanGestureRecognizer, UIPinchGestureRecognizer, UIRotationGestureRecognizer etc are added.

Normally it works fine,
 but when the view is scaled by CGAffineTransformScale , the UIImageView stops responding to pan gesture after a limit. Still the pinch and rotation will work on.
If the UIImageView in scaled backed to smaller, the UIPanGesture starts working again.

Comment: I have just come across this behaviour with panning in a scrollview, once the image is sized larger then panning stops until it’s sized smaller, did you ever find out the reason? Thanks for your help